# Java: using loops with no pre-defined stopping condition

Tags: java, loops

I have to write a program which keeps track of items scanned by 2 employees in a bar-code reader. It should

1. Allow input of the codes for the different items.
2. Display an error message each time an employee is scanning an item which he has already scanned.
3. Display the total number of items scanned by each employee.
4. Display the total number of different items present in the warehouse.

Basically, since I have not been told how many items are present I am wondering if I should use a loop for this or not? If yes, which loop should I use?

I do not want the code for the whole program. I just want to know if I need to use a loop and which one..

I used a for loop at first until I realized that it was wrong to assume the number of items present. I did only the first 2 parts:

```
public class MyClass1{

 public static void main(String[] args) {

    Set<Integer> h= new HashSet<Integer>();

    Scanner input= new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Employee 1:");
    for(int i=0;i<5;i++){
         boolean s= h.add(input.nextInt());

         if(!s){

             System.out.println("Item already exist!");
         }



    }

     System.out.println("Employee 2:"); 

     for(int x=0;x<5;x++){
         boolean sh= h.add(input.nextInt());

         if(!sh){

             System.out.println("Item already exist!");
         }  

     }

  }
}
```

Comment: What you have tried till now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this I would suggest you use a while loop.

```
// This loop will loop until the if statement's condition evaluates to true.
while(true){
    // Code for processing the input et.c
    if(someCondition) break; // The "break" keyword exits the last entered loop
    // Code for processing the input et.c
}
```

Comment: What will the condition in the _if_ statement?

Comment: If, as you say, there is no predefined stopping condition, then there is no `if` condition to check. You'll have to terminate the program manually. It would be nice to have a scanner code defined as the stop condition when the bar code scanner reads it.